# Downloading a file based on href of a HTML element

Tags: java, ftp, download, jsoup

I am creating an Application in Java that does parsing of HTML and get all the `<audio>`, `<img>` and `<video>` tags. I did this using jsoup. I have the attribute `href`, and therefore I get the link, I want a way to download the file to my PC through the tag. Is that possible through Java?

I saw a common format is `ftp://user:password@host:port/filePath;type=i.` but I dont know FTP for sites then how i can download the images and links.

Comment: If it's href and the source is a href, you won't need ftp.  It's just an HTTP resource.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First just get the absolute URL from the href attribute in Jsoup using [`Node#absUrl()`](http://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Node.html#absUrl%28java.lang.String%29).

```
String absUrl = element.absUrl("href");
```

Then you can get an [`InputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/InputStream.html) out of it using [`URL#openStream()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/net/URL.html#openStream%28%29).

```
InputStream input = new URL(absUrl).openStream();
```

Then you can write it to an arbitrary [`OutputStream`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/OutputStream.html) [the usual way](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/). E.g. to a `FileOutputStream`.

```
OutputStream output = new FileOutputStream(somepath);
// Just write input to output the usual way.
```

Note that this all has nothing to do with FTP. That's a completely different subject.

Comment: is that file be saved as in its orignal format? I mean jpeg as jpeg and mp3 as mp3?

Comment: Sure. As long as you use `InputStream`/`OutputStream` and not `Reader`/`Writer`, of course ;) On the other hand, why would you expect that I would post an answer which would possibly corrupt the files...?

Comment: Just the local disk file system path the usual way...? E.g. `"C:/path/to/file.ext"`. You can if necessary dynamically build it based on the value of the `href` with simple `String` manipulation methods such as `substring()`, `split()`, `concat()`, etc. That's all just covered in chapter 1 of a sane Java tutorial.

Comment: thank you,I dont know how you are writing to the output variable,you have given no reference to input..

Comment: The input is just `InputStream input = new URL(absUrl).openStream();`, exactly as shown in the answer...? How to write `InputStream` to `OutputStream` is covered in every basic Java IO tutorial. Do I have to write the whole tutorial out here? There's one already linked behind the "the usual way" phrase in my answer. If you click through to "Byte Streams" chapter, then you'll see a complete example.